# Coldfusion mapping cfinclude

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc, application.cfc

I am trying to use mappings for the first time and I am having some issues. In my CFadmin I created a mapping which goes like this:

Logical Path:

> /email_sender

Directory Path:

> E:\sites\Example.Com\cf_modules\autoresponders\Emails\emailLists

I am trying to access the include file from a .cfc. Inside my cfc I have an include file which is in the same folder and it works just fine but that include file is tying to access another include file based on the information I am passing through.

The include file inside the component has this code in it.

```
<cfmail from="#emailData.sender#" to="#surveymain.email#" subject="#subject#"  type="HTML" >
    <cfinclude template="#emailData.includePath#" >
</cfmail>
```

Just to be more clear this is my total filesystem:

> access.cfm -> some.cfc -> include_1 (works) -> include_2 (issue with
>   the path)

I have a try/catch which emails me the errors and it is located inside the include_1.

How can I use the mapping that I created to finally be able to access my include file?

Please note that after `emailLists` I have dynamic folders which change depending on which client I am trying to send the email to. So the end result of the path would be:

```
E:\sites\Example.Com\cf_modules\autoresponders\Emails\emailLists\client_A\email_template.cfm
```

I tried using my mapping by doing this
 `<cfinclude template="/email_sender/#emailData.includePath#" >`

which gave me this error:

> The path to the CFC must be specified as a full path, or as a relative
>   path from the current template, without the use of mappings.

Also, I tried including a full path in the cfinclude whic also resulted in the following error:

> Note: If you wish to use an absolute template path (for example, >template="/mypath/index.cfm") with CFINCLUDE, you must create a
>   mapping for the path using the ColdFusion Administrator. Or, you can
>   use per-application settings to specify mappings specific to this
>   application by specifying a mappings struct to THIS.mappings in
>   Application.cfc. 
>  Using relative paths (for example,
>   template="index.cfm" or template="../index.cfm") does not require the
>   creation of any special mappings. It is therefore recommended that you
>   use relative paths with CFINCLUDE whenever possible.

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated

Edit:
After restarting the server the version that worked was this one:
 `<cfinclude template="/email_sender/#emailData.includePath#" >`

Thanks to those who replied.

Comment: have you restarted the server since you added the mapping?

Comment: of course it had to be this.... Thanks for reminding me that...It works fine now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some questions, rather than some answers.

1. Did you set the mapping in CFAdmin or in Application.cfc?
2. What do you get if you run the code below?

   #expandPath("/email_sender")#
3. What is the value of `#emailData.includePath#`?
4. What is the value of this: `#expandPath("/email_sender#emailData.includePath#")#`?
5. Can you provide us with the exact text of the error messages, rather than vaguely describing them.
6. What is the value of `#fileExists(expandPath("/email_sender#emailData.includePath#"))#`?

If you can update your question with that info, you'll either spot where you're going wrong, or we can help to work out what the story is

Comment: I appreciate your answer my friend but unfortunately( or fortunately) my only mistake was that I forgot to restart my application server.

Comment: Chuckle.  Oh well.  Usually one doesn't need to restart the server for a mapping creation/change though, so that's a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me once before. Essentially we edited the xml file, rather than using the admin interface. It wasn't until our sys admin restarted the server until we realized why the mapping hadn't taken. So have you restarted the server since you added the mapping?

Comment: yes that was my issue. After I restarted the server everything works fine. i hope this post will help someone in the future from making the same mistake

Comment: I think the *mistake* here is messing with the config files rather than doing it via Application.cfc or the CFAdmin UI (or even the CFAdmin API!). Still: I guess you're working now, so that's the main thing.

Comment: @AdamCameron I did it through the CFAdmin but I still had to restart the CF Application Service